# Error Handling with Apache Camel and ActiveMQ - so breaking out of pipeline for exchange

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, error-handling, apache-camel, activemq-classic

I've been back and forth with an issue on our system that even with some research around the forums and several tests, we can't seem to be able to fix.

I'll try to be as clear as I can with what we are dealing with

We have a main service with a route that reads from an activemq queue ( spring boot with embedded broker ) sends it to a Route(B) and then ships everything to a final Route(C) . Route(B) is on a dependency of the service.

Camel Version: 3.3.0
Spring-boot version: 2.3.3.RELEASE

Route A:

```
 onException(Exception::class.java)
            .handled(true)
            .bean("foo.ErrorProcessor", "processError")

 from("activemq:queue:myqueue")
            .routeId("myroute")
            .to("direct:my_external_route")
            .to(ExchangePattern.InOnly,"direct:myroute_result")
```

Route B:

```
 onException(Exception::class.java)
            .handled(true)
            .bean("foo.ErrorProcessor", "processError")

 from("direct:my_external_route")
            .routeId("my_external_route")
            .process {something()} //This processor can throw exceptions that are treated in our processor
```

Route C:

```
from("direct:myroute_result")
      .process(someProcess())
      .to(ExchangePattern.InOnly,"activemq:queue:results_queue")
```

Spring Boot activemq configs

```
spring:
  jmx:
    enabled: true
  activemq:
    broker-url: vm://localhost?broker.persistent=false,useShutdownHook=false
    in-memory: true
    non-blocking-redelivery: true
    packages:
      trust-all: false
      trusted: com.mypackage
    pool:
      block-if-full: true
      block-if-full-timeout: -1
      enabled: false
      idle-timeout: 30000
      max-connections: 10
      time-between-expiration-check: -1
      use-anonymous-producers: true
```

Everything runs very well and smoothly when B's processors do not throw exceptions. When it does, even though they are being treated and a normal object is being returned in the message body, all we have on the logs is

```
2021-04-10 15:33:32.354 DEBUG [#1 - JmsConsumer[consumerName]] o.a.c.p.Pipeline                   
: Message exchange has failed: so breaking out of pipeline for exchange: Exchange[ID-1234] Handled by the error handler. {}
```

We even added a default error handler to our activemq connection factory but nothing happens there as well. We have a DLQ consumer who also does not seems to get anything. The error processor on routeA also does not catches anything which is expected since the exception was handled previously.

Has anyone ever had this issue or similar ? I know that some issues between Camel and the JMS component regarding error handling were raised in the past but we are struggling to understand what is the root of this issue.

Thanks in advance,
Pedro

Answer (score 0):

Probably what you are looking for is the **continued** option on your Route B exception clause. This option allows you to continue routing to the original route as if the exception did not occur. Do not use the **handled** option as it will not allow routing to the original route but break out.
So your Route B should be defined as something like this:

`onException(Exception::class.java)`
    `.continued(true)`
    `.bean("foo.ErrorProcessor", "processError")`

`from("direct:my_external_route")`
   `.routeId("my_external_route")`
   `.process {something()}`

Refer the camel documentation for more details: [CAMEL EXCEPTION CLAUSE](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/exception-clause.html)